# apache ldap auth per folder

Tags: apache, authentication, ldap

I have configured an apache server on redhat 6.
I have also implemented and teste ldap authentication, and it works.
The issue that i have is when i want to give rights to a user to a specific folder path...for example:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/x">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Enter Your AD Username/Password"
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    AuthzLDAPAuthoritative on
    AuthLDAPBindDN ....
    AuthLDAPBindPassword ....
    AuthLDAPURL ....
    require user user1 user2
</Directory>
```

and user3 to have access only to the

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/x/y">
 AuthType Basic
 AuthName "Enter Your AD Username/Password"
 AuthBasicProvider ldap
 AuthzLDAPAuthoritative on
 AuthLDAPBindDN ....
 AuthLDAPBindPassword ....
 AuthLDAPURL ....
 require user user3
</Directory>
```

I did what is written above but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in httpd use location, not Directory.

LDAPS can have trouble connecting if authzldapauthoritative is on.
This gave me an error 9 out of 10 times, when it's off it works just fine.

```
<Location "/var/www/html/x/y">
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Enter Your AD Username/Password"
  AuthBasicProvider "ldap"
  AuthLDAPURL "..."
  AuthLDAPBindDN "..."
  AuthLDAPBindPassword "..."
  authzldapauthoritative Off
  require valid-user
</Location>
```

or else use .htacces in each folder.

```
AuthLDAPBindDN "..."
AuthLDAPBindPassword "..."
AuthLDAPURL "..."

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Enter Your AD Username/Password"
AuthBasicProvider ldap

require valid-user
```